# Is an array argument passed to a function not a constant pointer?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Consider the code:

```
void foo(char a[]){
   a++;            //  works fine, gets compiled
   //... 
}
```

Now, consider this:

```
void foo(){
   char a[50];
   a++;            //  Compiler error
   //... 
}
```

I heard an array is equivalent to a constant pointer and can't be incremented as it is not a lvalue...

Then why does first code gets compiled, is it so because array arguments to functions are passed as a pointer, i.e. T[] is converted to T* for passing..
So, foo(a) passes a as a pointer.

But is it not back converted to T[] again because is declared as:

```
void foo(char a[]);
```

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you pass an array as an argument to a function, it decays to a pointer.
So the thing you increment inside the function body is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: In particular, it's as if you declared `char *temp = a;` then incremented `temp`.

Answer (score 11):

This is a rather unfortunate feature inherited from the C language, with the rather yucky name of "decay." Since C once did not allow passing compound types by value, they decided to allow programmers to specify arrays as function parameter types, but only cosmetically. The array type decays to a pointer type, implementing a sort of pass-by-reference semantic different from the rest of the language. Ugly.

To recap (and others have already said this), the signature

```
void foo(char a[]); // asking for trouble
```

is unceremoniously mangled into

```
void foo(char *a);
```

… all for the sake of compatibility with ancient C code. Since you aren't writing ancient C code, you should not make use of this "feature."

However, you can cleanly pass a *reference* to an array. C++ requires that the size of the array be known:

```
void foo( char (&a)[ 50 ] );
```

Now `a` cannot be modified within the function (edit: its *contents* can, of course — you know what I mean), and only arrays of the right size may be passed. For everything else, pass a pointer or a higher-level type.

Answer (score 4):

> I heard an array is equivalent to a constant pointer

You *can* think of it that way, but they're not equivalent.

An array decays to a pointer when passed to a function, that's why inside the function it's valid.

Just because the signature is `void foo(char a[])` doesn't make `a` an array.

Outside the function, it's just an array, and you can't do pointer arithmetics on it.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, any function parameter of type "array of T" is adjusted to be "pointer to T". Try this code:

```
void foo(char a[]) {}  
void foo(char* a) {}  //error: redefinition
```

They are indeed the same function.

So, why can we pass an array argument to a function as a pointer parameter? Not because an array is equivalent to a constant pointer, but because an array type can be implicitly converted to an rvalue of pointer type. Also note the result of the conversion is an rvalue, that's why you can't apply the operator ++ to an array, you can only apply this operator to an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an array a[] to a function, it passes the value of 'a', an address, into the function. so you can use it as a pointer in the function. If you declare an array in the function, 'a' is constant because you can't change its address in memory.

Answer (score 1):

> I heard an array is equivalent to a constant pointer and can't be incremented as it is not a lvalue...

Almost.

An array *expression* is a *non-modifiable lvalue*; it may not be an operand to operators such as `++` or `--`, and it may not be the target of an assignment expression.  This is not the same thing as a constant pointer (that is, a pointer declared as `T * const`).

An array expression will be replaced with a pointer expression whose value is the address of the first element of the array *except* when the array expression is an operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or when the array expression is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration.

When you call a function with an array argument, such as

```
int a[N];
...
foo(a);
```

the *expression* `a` is converted from type "N-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`" and this pointer value is what gets passed to `foo`; thus, the corresponding function prototype should be

```
void foo (int *arr) {...}
```

Note that in the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are identical to `T *a`; in all three cases, `a` is declared as a pointer to `T`.  Within the function `foo`, the parameter `arr` is a pointer expression, which *is* a modifiable lvalue, and as such it may be assigned to and may be the operand of the `++` and `--` operators.

Remember that all these conversions are on the array *expression*; that is, the array identifier or other expression that refers to the array *object* in memory.  The array object (the chunk of memory holding the array values) is not converted.