# Incrementing array of pointers as a formal argument compiled and executed

Tags: c++, c

As we can't increment base address of an array, the following code won't compile.

```
int main(void)
{
    /* Array of pointers initialization */
    char *argv[] = {"hello", "world"};

    puts(*++argv);  // Gives compile time error
    return 0;
}
```

But I am unable to figure out why the following code compiled and executed successfully. The formal argument of `func(char *argv[])` is also an array of pointers right?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char *argv[])
{
    puts(*++argv);  //Compiles fine
}

int main(void)
{
    char *argv[] = {"hello", "world"};

    func(argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Anybody please explain the mechanism behind it.

Comment: Indeed a duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963080/is-an-array-argument-passed-to-a-function-not-a-constant-pointer solved my problem.